# External table 'logdata' is not accessible because location does not exist or it is used by another proces

Tags: t-sql, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am try to create an external table on Azure Synapse by once I run `select * from logdata` I get the error "External table 'logdata' is not accessible because location does not exist or it is used by another proces"

below is my code

````
CREATE DATABASE appdb;

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD =<>

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL SasToken
WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET=<>

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE log_data
WITH (
LOCATION='https://<>.dfs.core.windows.net/data',
CREDENTIAL=SasToken
)

CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT TextFileFormat WITH(
    FORMAT_TYPE=DELIMITEDTEXT,
    FORMAT_OPTIONS(
        FIELD_TERMINATOR=',',
        FIRST_ROW=2
    )
 )

 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE logdata(
    [Id] INT,
    [Correlationid] VARCHAR (200),
    [Operationname] VARCHAR (200),
    [Status] VARCHAR (200), 
    [Eventcategory] VARCHAR (200),
    [Level]  VARCHAR (200),
    [Time]  DATETIME,
    [Subscription]  VARCHAR (200),
    [Eventinitiatedby]   VARCHAR (1000),
    [Resourcetype] VARCHAR (1000),  
    [Resourcegroup] VARCHAR (1000)
 )
 WITH(
 LOCATION='/Log.csv',
 DATA_SOURCE=log_data,
 FILE_FORMAT=TextFileFormat
)

-- drop EXTERNAL table logdata ;

 SELECT * from logdata;
```
````

```
I tried changing the access levels but couldn't work either.
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need the necessary access rights to the file in order to fix this problem. The simplest method is to give yourself the "`Storage Blob Data Contributor`" role on the storage account that you are trying to query.

And also check the details you entered while creating the external table in synapse. **The location's URL is case-sensitive.** and make sure your file is present at the destination.

**Correct Syntax/code to create External Table:**

```sql
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD ='Welcome@Pratik123';

CREATE  DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyCred
WITH  IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET='SAS Token';

CREATE  EXTERNAL  DATA SOURCE MyDs2
WITH (
LOCATION='abfss://containername@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/foldername if any',
CREDENTIAL=MyCred
)

CREATE  EXTERNAL  FILE FORMAT MyFile2 WITH(
FORMAT_TYPE=DELIMITEDTEXT,
FORMAT_OPTIONS(
FIELD_TERMINATOR=',',
FIRST_ROW=2
)
)

CREATE  EXTERNAL  TABLE MyData3(
[Id] varchar(20),
[NAME] VARCHAR (200),
[ADDRESS] VARCHAR (200)
)
WITH(
LOCATION='/dataaddress.csv',
DATA_SOURCE=MyDs2,
FILE_FORMAT=MyFile2
)

SELECT * from MyData3;
```

**My output:**

[image]

refer this similar error [example by- Mike Stephenson](https://www.mikestephenson.me/2021/08/02/synapse-external-table-not-accessible/)